# Dart/Flutter : The meaning of "whether some code is annotated or inferred is orthogonal to whether it is dynamic or some other type"

Tags: flutter, dart

https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#types

> If the code is type annotated, the type was explicitly written in the
> code.
>
> If the code is inferred, no type annotation was written, and Dart
> successfully figured out the type on its own. Inference can fail, in
> which case the guidelines don’t consider that inferred.
>
> If the code is dynamic, then its static type is the special dynamic
> type. Code can be explicitly annotated dynamic or it can be inferred.
>
> In other words, whether some code is annotated or inferred is
> orthogonal to whether it is dynamic or some other type.

The above explanation is extremely abstract and I'm not sure exactly what this means.

Especially the last sentence, does it mean that "it may be inferred as another type even though it is type-annotated as'dyanmic'"?

But maybe I feel it's not right.

Because I remember being told by the IDE during development that something like "because it's a dynamic type, you can't access that member."

If not, I would like a more specific explanation of what it means after all.
It would be helpful if you could get some clues.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, a variable can be type annotated:

```
int x = 1;
```

also, it can be inferred:

```
var x = 1; // dart knows x is an integer because you assigned 1 to it.
```

A variable can be dynamic, meaning it's type can change.

That's what the three first sentences mean, the last sentence is saying that a dynamic variable can be either inferred or annotated:

```
dynamic someFunction() {
  return 1;
}

dynamic x = 'aaa'; // annotated
var y = someFunction(); // inferred
```

So weather a variable is annotated or inferred has nothing to do with weather it is dynamic or not.